# Error "Source file does not exist" during building build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I am running ant and get error:

> build.xml:1004: Source file does not exist!

on 1004 string I see:

```
<macrodef name="run-sql-file">
    <attribute name="file.name"/>
    <attribute name="user"/>
    <attribute name="password"/>
    <sequential>
        <sql
                driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                classpath="${templateResources}/genericLibs/ojdbc14.jar"
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${ds_server}:${ds_sid}"
                userid="@{user}"
                password="@{password}"
                src="@{file.name}"
                >
        </sql>//it's 1004 string
    </sequential>
```

How can I understand what file needs for ant?

Thanks.

edit1.

1045 string:

```
<target name="sql" depends="drop-all-tables, drop-all-sequences">
    <!-- DDL : tables & stuff -->
    <echo message="Purging 10g recyclebin"/>
    <sql-query sql="PURGE RECYCLEBIN" user="${ds_username}" password="${ds_password}"/>

    <run-sql-file file.name="${data}/ddl/tables.jdbc.sql" user="${ds_username}" password="${ds_password}"/> //1045
```

Comment: Sounds like it is complaining about src="@{file.name}"

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how can I know exactly what file it needs?

Comment: Is the file referenced by:  ${data}/ddl/tables.jdbc.sql   available?

Comment: Thank you! I decided my issue. I rename directory from ddl to DDL and problemis gone.